# Where is Facebook “live to group” video cached on Android Nexus 6P?

Tags: android, facebook

I have tried going live using the Pages Manager app, and within a Group doing a live feed update.

Both resulted in this error.
[image: facebook error image width]

I can do live video update to my profile without this error.
Know where I can find the locally stored video/ cached file? So I can upload that?

Phone: Google Nexus 6P

Comment: note that there is nothing special about Nexus 6P. Facebook stores it's data on every device the same way

Comment: Thanks Vlad, where exactly is that?

Comment: If I knew, I'd post an answer. You can use some root file manager to investigate by yourself